# Работа с дочерними вложенными элементами в WPF

Tags: wpf, c#

Как можно в технологии WPF из, например, Grid, в котором все дочерние элементы Border, а в Border находятся Image, пройтись Foreach по всем Image?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать используя следующий метод:

```
public class VisualHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
          if (depObj != null)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
              DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
              if (child != null && child is T)
              {
                yield return (T) child;
              }

              foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
              {
                yield return childOfChild;
              }
            }
          }
        }
}
```

Далее:

```
foreach (var image in VisualHelper.FindVisualChildren<Image>(layoutGrid))
{
    // use image variable here
}
```